# Customize Contour Labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, label, ggplot2, contour

I'm relatively new to ggplot2, and I'm having trouble adding appropriate labels to my contours. I would love to be able to add the labels without the directlabels package, but I haven't found a way to, so if you know of a way to customize labels without directlabels, I would love to here it.

Using the classic volcano example, I can add labels to the default contour plot using the directlabels packet in the following way:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(reshape)
volcano<-melt(volcano)
v<-ggplot(volcano, aes(x,y,z=z))
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..))
direct.label(e)
```

In the above example, the labels are added appropriately, but things become more complicated if I try to specify my own break points for the contours:

```
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(breaks=c(160, 170, 180), colour=..level..))
direct.label(e)
```

Now, the contours are specified by the breaks I have provided, but labels still appear for all of the default contours. How do I only plot only labels for the graphed contours?

A related issue, how would I plot labels for contour levels not included in the default? Say a break of 165:

```
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(breaks=c(165), colour=..level..))
direct.label(e)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: Also, the example you gave does not appear to work. The column names produced by melt are `c(X1,X2,value)` meaning that `v <- ggplot(volcano, aes(x = X1, y= X2, z = value))` will work.

Comment: @mnel and @BurtonGuster I just tried to run examples from `?direct.label` using `ggplot2` (0.9.1) and `directlabel` (2.5), and each time got an error message: "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class waiver".  There could be a problem with the `directlabels` package - [see here](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/directlabels/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

The current development version (directlabels_2013.6.15 with ggplot2_0.9.3.1) should fix your problem (as the author of the directlabels package explained to me). You can install it with:

```
install.packages("directlabels", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
```

And then:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(reshape)
volcano<-melt(volcano)
v<-ggplot(volcano, aes(X1,X2,z=value))
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..), breaks=c(165))
direct.label(e)
```

I noted several other limitations with simple workarounds:

- the first `ggplot` call must contain the `z` aesthetic
- this works only with the `stat_contour` (and not with the `geom_contour`)
- the `colour` aesthetic must be defined in the `stat_contour` call and set to `..level..`

Finally, if you want to control the label and contour line colours (black labels and blue contour lines for instance), you can achieved this as follow:

```
e<-v + stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..), colour = "blue", breaks=c(165))
e<-e + scale_colour_continuous(low = "#FF0000", high = "#FF0000")
direct.label(e)
```

Comment: How can I make `direct.label` return the modified ggplot2 object instead of drawing it on the screen?